# Setup a PostgreSQL HA with synchronous replication in windows

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

I am fairly new to postgres ans would like recommendations for setting up HA system in windows Server machines. My current plan is to run 2 server Primary (Data center) with postgres 9.6 and same setup in Recovery Center. planning to setup postgres in streaming mode. I am focusing on DB replication model.What kind of replication should I have between the 2 servers ? Is something synchronous feasible.

I did try the replication process with hot standby mode in postgres, But have some confusions which needs some guidance.

Configuration Steps: https://pastebin.com/7DJAvnPr

*Consideration:

DB is successfully configured in streaming mode "hot standby" (Primary) DC server --> (Secondary) DR Server

Network failure switching to secondary server will be done automatically during permanent failures FROM DC to DR

Network Switching back will be done automatically from DR to DC

*OS : Windows server , DB : Postgres 9.6*

**Normal Operation:**

With hot standby, the replication is working as expected and DB is getting synced as expected.

**Operation live in secondary Server:**

Since the DB is already in sync state all my required info are intact with my DC.

*since the postegres in setup in slave mode,which is read-only in my case. We were not able to write data in DB.*

> Would like to understand is there any internal PostgreSQL mechanism
>   available for making this DB as master

or

> *Should i reset the posgres configuration to master and restart postgres service*

**Recovered state (switching back from DR server to DC server):**

I am not able to visualize what should be done. and how should we proceed with the DB sync from secondary to primary. Would like some advise here

​

** I know I got Windows machines and I can make a Windows Cluster(that postgresql listener I wanted) and It should failover automatically between the postgresql windows services in case one stops.

Comment: Did you get any success in setting up PostgreSQL HA Cluster.

Comment: To an extent we have complete working model

Comment: Could you please answer your question now? also, it would be great if you can share your HA Solution so that others can benefit from this.